# Splitting FullName Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The column `Staff_Name` lists the name as "Doe, John A".
I need this to be separated into 2 columns like below:

```
Last Name | First Name
Doe       | John A
```

Heres the code I have but I need it to remove the "," that it outputs

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Staff_Name, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Staff_Name)))) As [Physician First Name],
 LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(Staff_Name, CHARINDEX(' ', Staff_Name)+1, 8000)))As [Physician Last Name]
```

Here is what the code is currently outputting:

```
Last Name | First Name    
Doe,      | John A
```

Comment: tag your database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `,` instead of space to remove the comma.

```
CHARINDEX(',', Staff_Name)
```